# What version of Java hamcrest-all v1.3 compatible with?

Tags: java, hamcrest

I can not find any information about the question:
What version of Java hamcrest-all v1.3 compatible with?

Comment: Looks like [1.7](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/build.gradle#L1), but why don't you [ask project developers directly](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code for [Hamcrest 1.3](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/releases/tag/hamcrest-java-1.3) the file `BUILDING.txt` includes this statement:

```
--[ Build requirements ]-------------------------------------

* JDK 1.5
  Note: that this is a buildtime dependency for 1.5 specific
  features. However the final built jars should run on 1.4
  and 1.3 JVMs with some features unavailable.
```

This is further supported by the `javac` command in the Ant `build.xml` ...

```
<javac srcdir="@{srcdir}" destdir="build/temp/@{modulename}-${version}.jar.contents" 
    debug="${debug}" target="1.5" includeantruntime="false">
    ...
</javac>
```

So, it looks like Hamcrest 1.3 is compatible with Java 1.5 but according to the authors ...

> it should run on 1.4 and 1.3 JVMs with some features unavailable

By contrast, Hamcrest 2.x presumes Java 1.7, from the [build.gradle](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/build.gradle):

```
import static org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

sourceCompatibility = VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = VERSION_1_7
```